# Tips for "better" white space

Tags: design, web, css

I am currently working on the front end of a key server.
The problem that I am having, is that i have got many pages, which do not hold much information and I do not know, how I can fill out the white space of the pages more evenly.

Currently all of the information of the pages is on the left side, which leaves the center and the right side a bit empty.

Could someone give me feedback on how i could improve my page, to fill the whitespace or make it look more evenly spread?

Thanks for any tips!

[image: Page to add a new key server, to synchronize both]

[image: Page to give certain parameters a certain quantifier]

Answer (score 4):

You can reduce the display area and center. Header can remain full screen.

> [image: list to size]

.

If you have many to display make rows of cells.

> [image: rows and columns]

.

Or put your data for each item in a single row.

> [image: single row]